# Mac catalina xcode c++, access file pop_up

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-catalina

I use Xcode to write c++ programs. My programs contains

```
freopen("./input.txt", "r", stdin);
```

every time I change my code and click build and run, there is a pop-up that ask for permisson.

```
"cpp_binary" would like to access documents folder
```

This is just annoying as I change my code and rebuild frequently.

How can I bypass this annoying pop-up.

I have tried grant the cpp_binary full disk access right, but it seems that since I changed the code and rebuild, Mac catalina recognize the newly built binary as a different app, and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem exists because I put my xcode project in documents foler.

After I move the project to ~ (/Users/myusername), the issue goes away.

Comment: Not a real solution. The OS shouldn't interfere with my opinion of the best place in my filesystem to store my projects, through annoying popups that make you so tired of clicking them that you give up and store your files somewhere else that's less obvious to you. Have you found another workaround?